# How to run an Android VM on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to run an Android VM on GCE. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcR6ZLebTM) to build my own vm image from Android 4.4 x86 iso image. I could start an instance using the image I built, but I cannot SSH to it or I couldn't adb connect to it. Can anyone help me how to make the Android VM work on GCE?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same and am wondering whether or not the fact that the Android x86 images are all 32 bit whereas GCE apparently [only supports 64 bit images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/).

*EDIT*: Ravello Systems seems to have a KVM-like solution that is deployed to GCE as a custom hypervisor image that sits on top of your Android VM image, providing a nested virtualized environment. That's the only way I was able to test this out. Check the [following blog article](http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/android-cloud-running-kitkat-ec2/).

PS: I did install an SSH server on the image before uploading as well but I don't think the VM is even booting as I can't ping it either.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial mentions that you have to make sure that the image contains an SSH agent so that you'll be able to access it after it finishes installing. The Android 4.4 x86 doesn't have any SSH component so it's expected that it doesn't allow SSH connections. You'll need to add an SSH agent in the image in order to make SSH-able.

Comment: I have tried that, too! Unfortunately, with no luck! Thanks for the suggestion, though!